# The child view set to app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" cannot be displayed

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

The child View of ConstraintLayout is set `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"` to hide at the bottom of the screen. Just after entering the Activity, when it pops up at the bottom of the screen through `animate().translationYBy()` on the Android 7.1 virtual machine, nothing happens.

After clicking the desktop key or the recent task key, and then switching back to Activity, the child View does appear. But I don't have this problem on the Android 10 virtual machine.

The visibility and size of the childView are all correct at the beginning of the animation.

When I add `android:layout_marginTop="-1px"` this line of code to the childView to make the childView show 1 pixel at the bottom of the screen, everything is normal!

What went wrong? How can I modify？

Code show as below :

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/childView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```kotlin
childView.animate().translationYBy(childView.measuredHeight.toFloat()).setDuration(200)
            .setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
                    isAnimating = true
                    isShowing = true
                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                    isAnimating = false
                }

                override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
                    isAnimating = false
                }

                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
                }
            }).start()
```

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
```

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The child View of ConstraintLayout is set app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" to hide at the bottom of the screen.

But there's no need for you to hide it at the screen's bottom since it's the only child. But if you insist, I suggest that you change this line:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
```

to

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 

app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 

app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

It'll work very fine.

Comment: I need the childView to implement a function like the bottom drawer, and my Activity does not only have this childView. In order to simplify the code, I only wrote the childView.

Comment: That means you'll be making use of sliding drawer. A sliding always have an icon at it's top where you can drag view to cover parent layout. But for now, is the childView visible

Comment: DrawerLayout can only support side sliding, not up and down drawers.

Comment: Sliding drawer is different from Drawer Layout. Since Sliding drawer is deprecated, i think this [GitHub library] is good https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel